# Sync mac iCal calendar with outlook calendar

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, iphone, calendar, calendar.app

I'm using both iPhone (iOS 12) and Mac (Catalina).

**iPhone mail client**: Gmail

**Mac mail client**: Spark

**Mails boxes**: Outlook, iCloud

Somehow, on my iPhone all events: both which are created by me directly in calendar app and that ones that came from Outlook (both created by my own and invitations) are all displayed in calendar app.

However, I can't reach the same result for iCal calendar on my Mac. I have just events which are created by me directly in calendar app. Such events are correctly syncing between Mac and iPhone. On the other hand, I can't find a way to integrate Outlook events into iCal app.

What I've tried?
I've created iCloud email just to integrate my iCloud events into the Spark app, according [to this article](https://helpspot.readdle.com/en/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=1412).

Basically, it works, but this is not what I really wanted to achieve. I want to add all Outlook events to native iCal app instead of using Spark client, which just integrates all mail calendars.

I do believe that that the solution is to "put a tick" somewhere because it works out of the box on my iPhone. I don't want to use any thirdparty software, which syncs calendars like [sync-mac](https://www.sync-mac.com/sync-outlook-calendar-mac.html) as it looks like huge overhead.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution and as I told it's very easy.

on Mac:

Settings -> Internet accounts -> Add account -> Exchange -> Enter your Outlook credentials -> check "Sync Mail" button.

Voila, all Outlook events are displayed in your iCal.